# mechanism that prevents OutOfMemory exception before it happened java

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, heap-size

How can we predict or check if an `OutOfMemory` error will happen before creating a new instance? This mechanism must tell me that if I were to create one more object then an `OutOfMemory` error will occur.

what mechanism used for OutOfMemory handling.

Any solutions for this issue?

Comment: thanks, Hulk. but it doesn't solve my problem, I need an optimal and reliable solution

Comment: Well, and the answer is that such a solution does not exist in java. Even if you check first, the next allocation can still fail, and you need to handle the Exception. You can do both, as that will reduce the likelyhood of the Excpetion, though, and that is probably the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's very difficult (impossible?) to predict the memory state of the moment you decide to actually create the new object (other objects created, GC triggered, ...)
Even a "test creation" is not reliable as it modify this state.

I'm really curious if someone has a clear solution on that.

I think I would go wrapping the object creation and managing the Exception the best I can.